# Delete files based on backlist word

Tags: shell, unlink, blacklist

I am looking for bash on linux or php file

file: cron.php or cron.sh

dir: /files

blacklist: blacklist.txt

cron.php runs every minute and search for file names containing blacklist.

delete files based on file name

reason: clean download center from explicit files ;

---

```
$blacklist = 'blacklist.txt';
for each /files/*.*
echo 'deleted file: "$blacklist" <br>' ;
```

bash or php code for delete files based on backlist word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the blacklist words are written in a file named `blacklist.txt`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
list=/files/*$line*
for file in ${list[@]}
do
[[ -f $file ]] && rm $file
done
done < blacklist.txt
```

Comment: word containing , i havent full name of files to delete;

Comment: I misunderstood your situation, tell me if this is what you want. (edited my answer)

Comment: great; thanks my friend; tnx a lottttttttttt ! exatly removed files contain blacklist !

Answer (score 0):

Are the file paths in the `blacklist.txt` full paths? If so,

```
xargs rm < blacklist.txt
```

you may need the `-f` or `-r` flag depending on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

/files directory contain many files i dont know whats 
some files contain "+18" string or xxx or .. based on blacklist.txt

exp:

> /files/video_contain_+18_watch.mp4

this code should find it and remove it by blacklist words per line